# Email address verified on Amazon SES doesn't allow me to make rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gmail, imap, amazon-ses

I have created a AWS lambda function to receive emails sent to a gmail account. I have verified that account on SES to launch the lambda function but it doesn't work. When I set the rule, I write the email address verified but in the rule creation settings it tell me to verify the domain. Obviously gmail is not my domain, but I just want to receive emails from my account.

Using locally the function I can use imap server created with standar python library to receive emails, but this throw a login fail when I try to use it on lambda function without SES.

There is a way to verify my gmail address on SES? Or at least receive emails on a lambda function?

Comment: Possibly not.  Since gmail is aimed towards consumers, their security policy will break when used on hosted services, especially on massive cloud providers. If you implement OAuth, you may be able to get it to work, but it will almost assuredly not work with username and password.  You might be able to get it to work with an App Specific Password.

Answer (score 0):

To receive emails on your lambda, you should rely on gmail to push a notification to your topic. your lambda can be triggered the moment the notification arrives with the mailbox update notification. You'll have to invoke another api to get the corresponding message details and pass that into your lambda for further processing.